# NDEFReader is not Defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop nfc card login page.

web platform features enabled. ( also I reset all settings and enable it again)

My webpage is developing by using React and I'm reaching it(from tablet) by using localhost ip adress(my laptop adress)

NFC read and write are working on other pages like https://kenchris.github.io/webnfc-groceries/ but it doesn't work in my code.

I also added lib.web-nfc.d.js like typescript but it does not work. it returns error
[image]

That is the Code block
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Solution : https connection ( with or without trusted ssl does not matter)